# What can we interpret about the two random variables X and Y, if their Covariance (Cov(X, Y)) is greater than zero?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, covariance

Although I know mathematically how to prove that if Cov(X, Y) > 0 then that means the two variables are interdependent but can someone explain the non-mathematical approach of interpreting this with some sort of proof.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for. Wikipedia gives the following interpretation: In probability theory and statistics, covariance is a measure of the joint variability of two random variables. If the greater values of one variable mainly correspond with the greater values of the other variable, and the same holds for the lesser values, i.e., the variables tend to show similar behavior, the covariance is positive.

Comment: In the opposite case, when the greater values of one variable mainly correspond to the lesser values of the other, i.e., the variables tend to show opposite behavior, the covariance is negative. The sign of the covariance therefore shows the tendency in the linear relationship between the variables.

Comment: What I am asking of is a verbal proof of the same thing.